# Include shell script in python package and find path to package after installation

Tags: python, bash, setuptools

I have a Python package that includes a shell script. When the shell script is called, it needs to access other files that are part of the installation. I include the script in my `setup.py` as

```
scripts=['source_dir/utils/mybashscript'],
```

The problem now is that it will end up in `virtualenv_dir/bin/`. What I would want to do is get the absolute path to where the `source_dir/utils/` directory ends up after installation from within `mybashscript`.

Is there a workaround for this?

It's a rather standard python package setup like

```
mypackage/  
| -- setup.py  
| -- source_dir/  
|      | -- utils/  
|      |       | -mybashscript
```

Comment: One question: is `setup.py` in the same directory as `source_dir/utils/mybashscript`, or is it in `source_dir`? Could you provide some information as to where the files are in relation to each other?

Comment: It does not seem to have anything to do with Python or Setuptools. You should write the logic to find out the absolute location of the shell script in this same shell script. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128